# Difference between <SomeName()> and <SomeNameAttribute()> in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, attributes

Pretty much as the title, is there a difference between using and attribute `<SomeName()>` and `<SomeNameAttribute()>` where `SomeName` is the same in both cases?

for example in Newtonsoft's [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) there is `<JsonConverterAttribute()>` and `<JsonConverter()>` that can be applied to a member. According to the Object Browser both resolve to the same `JsonConverterAttribute` class. Is that a peculiarity of this particular attribute or framework, or does this hold for all VB.NET attributes?

Comment: No difference.  A simple trick to make attribute class names very specific but attribute usage very brief.  A trick invented by a programmer, not a committee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx):

> By convention, all attribute names end with the word "Attribute" to
>   distinguish them from other items in the .NET Framework. However, you
>   do not need to specify the attribute suffix when using attributes in
>   code.

So, an `Attribute` written as `MyFooAttribute` can be used as `MyFoo` or `MyFooAttribute` and will show as the same entry in Object Browser.  The value in this is to help prevent "name contortions" in a namespace: Newtonsoft has a `JsonConverter` Type but can also use essentially the same name as an `Attribute`.

The reverse is not true (at least in VS2012).  If you use the 'short form' for a custom attribute:

```
Public Class MyFoo
    Inherits Attribute
```

The attribute is legal and usable (owing to its inheritance) but `MyFooAttribute` wont be recognized in code nor found in Object Browser.  So for custom attributes, it pays to name the class as `MyFooAttribute`.

Comment: … and the corollary of this: to be consistent, always name your classes `FooAttribute`, and always *use* them as `<Foo()>`.